# Description of the "Scholar" badge

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges, wording

It currently says:

> > First accepted answer on your own question.

I find this very confusing since it appears to imply that you can accept an answer on someone else's question, and/or that you can accept more than one.

This is especially a concern since this is probably the easiest badge to acquire and therefore many inexperienced users will run into it.

I think it would be much more clear if we change it to:

> > Asked a question and accepted an answer.

(Note: I don't think it's necessary to specify that the badge cannot be awarded several times. Usually it's only specified if it can.)

Comment: +1. I seem to remember I found the wording rather strange and your proposed solution is much clearer.

Comment: If I remember right, I think when I first joined these sites, I got the Scholar badge before I even knew what a badge even was. haha ;)

Comment: [OT] I don't have any question-related badge because every time I think of a question to ask on SO, I search for it and it already exists.

Comment: Scholar was the last one I received (from 11). Am I doing something wrong???

Comment: Also, to stop spamming: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox

Comment: How about simply "First time accepting an answer"

Comment: @BlueRaja, why? You need to ask a question first, so in order to get the badge you need to do both. It's more clear if you specify it in the description.

Comment: I do think it should be clear if it is a one-time badge or a badge that you can get multiple times.

Comment: @thursdaysgeek It's sad, but you can only do things for the first time once.

Comment: @Daniel Daranas - True :).  I should have made it clear that if the wording of the badge were changed to "Asked a question and accepted an answer" -- THAT should indicate if it were a one-time badge or not.

Comment: I would like to suggest that a 'scholar' involves: genuine pursuit of knowledge (truth), researching, observing, questioning, seeking out an answer, and finally - on reflection, accepting what is discovered, then equipped with new and greater knowledge. :)

Answer (score 4):

I think a little modification maybe:

> **Asked a question and accepted an
>   answer for it.**